# rss in windows forms

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, rss, feed

I'm developing an application in windows forms with C#, and I'1d like to know How could I use Rss Toolkit in Windows Forms Application ? I've referenced in my solution but it doesn't work very fine, an error apper when I compile the app.

Is there any easy way to read Rss (Feeds) in Windows Forms ?

If someone can help me.. I appretiate!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using .NET 3.5 SP1, it already has [everything you need](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.aspx) in terms of syndication:

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("http://localhost/feeds/serializedFeed.xml");
SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
```